# Dealing with noise in NISQ

Tags: noise, nisq

I wanted to know if there are some way in NISQ (we run "bare" gate without Q.E.C) to certify if an algorithm will give a correct or wrong answer based on the process of a single gate ?

For example in fault tolerant quantum computing, if you know the X,Y or Z error of a single logical gate you can easily tell what will be the probability that your full algorithm is wrong.

Are there similar constructions for NISQ ?